# Yii2: dynamic style in contentOptions (GridView)

Tags: gridview, yii2

Is there a more elegant approach to dynamic styling in Yii2 than:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        [
           'attribute' => 'fecha',
           'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'color: '.$dataProvider->models[0]->fechaVerif->color],
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

aside using an anonymous function? I tried something like:

```
'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'color: '. fechaVerif.color]
```

but it obviously didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at Column::renderDataCell implementation in Yii2:

```
public function renderDataCell($model, $key, $index)
{
    if ($this->contentOptions instanceof Closure) {
        $options = call_user_func($this->contentOptions, $model, $key, $index, $this);
    } else {
        $options = $this->contentOptions;
    }
    return Html::tag('td', $this->renderDataCellContent($model, $key, $index), $options);
}
```

Therefore the only way to do what you want is:

```
            [
                'attribute' => 'fecha',
                'contentOptions' => function($model)
                    {
                        return ['style' => 'color:' . $model->fechaVerif->color];
                    }
            ],
```